# Replace Main Fragment with Child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments Fragment A is the main fragment and Fragment B is a child fragment. When clicking on fragment B , I want fragment C to replace the whole fragment A and navigate to it again when button back is pressed from C.
The problem that i can't solve is that the framelayout container is in Fragment A xml so what fragment container i should give to fragment C :

```
            Fragment fragment = new PetDetailFragment();
            String fragmentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragmentTag).commit();
```

[image]

Comment: onBack press of fragmentC which fragment you want A or B??

Comment: i want to return to fragment A

Answer (score 1):

when the user clicks on fragment B just execute

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, new FragmentC(), fragmentCTag).commit();
```

and then when the user presses back fragment A will be visible automatically. To display fragment A manually execute

```
getfragmentmanager().popbackstack()
```

Comment: but FragmentA.xml has the <FrameLayout> and fragmentC.xml doesn't how should i handle this ?

Comment: fragmentA and fragmentC both can be displayed using the same layout. FragmentA will be pushed to the backstack and fragment C will be on top. Once you press back button fragment C will be destroyed and fragment A will be visible again. It is the same as activity stack